# SSL errors installing hugo in blogdown

Tags: r, ssl, r-markdown, blogdown

I'm trying to install blogdown and hugo on my Linux machine running R 4.0.2. When I do `blogdown::install_hugo()` I get this error message:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : 
cannot open the connection to 'https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/latest'
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
URL 'https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/latest': status was 'Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)'
```

I started getting this error installing any package, including from CRAN, a couple of months ago. I fixed it with this helpful bit of code in my .Rprofile file:

```
options(download.file.method = "wget")
local({
         r<- getOption("repos");
         r["CRAN"] <-"https://cran.rstudio.com/"
         options(repos=r)
})
```

Now I have no problem installing and updating packages from CRAN but I can't install hugo. I tried reinstalling `curl` and `httr` but that did not help. It seems this problem first arose a month or so ago when I renewed my client certificate from cacert.org, but I don't know if it's related or not. All I did was install the renewed certificate in my browser so I don't think it has anything to do with this problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What OS version are you running?

Comment: Gentoo Linux, kernel version  5.4.72-gentoo #1 SMP

Comment: Can you run `wget https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/latest` from the command line? What exactly did you run when you renewed your client cert? It seems like somehow the trust authority got messed up.

Comment: ``wget`` got the file, no errors. To renew the cert I just clicked a box to select the certificate and clicked on Renew. Then I installed it in my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may download `hugo_extended_*_Linux-64bit.tar.gz` from https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/latest with your web browser, and pass the local file path to `install_hugo()` to install it, e.g.,

```r
blogdown::install_hugo('~/Downloads/hugo_extended_0.78.2_Linux-64bit.tar.gz')
```

Comment: That worked fine. Thank you! Since I install all R packages site-wide for all users, I install as root. It put the .js and hugo executables in $ROOT_USER/bin. I moved these to /usr/local/bin. I hope that's OK. Also, I hope I don't have the same problem installing themes. I'll try the same method. Any idea why I have this problem?

Comment: Oops. I missed the "extended" in your message and installed the plain version. Then I tried downloading and installing the extended version with install_hugo("...entended...", extended=TRUE, force=TRUE) but it give me this error: ``Error: invalid version specification `hugo_extended_0.78.2_Linux-64bit.tar.gz'``

Comment: @Stuart 1. Moving `hugo` to `/usr/local/bin` is fine. It is a self-contained binary. You can move it anywhere in your system. 2. The error you ran into was due to a bug in **blogdown**, which I just fixed on Github. Please try `remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')`. Sorry about that!

Comment: thanks but I still can't install anything from github. Keep getting the same error as in the OP: ``Error: Failed to install 'blogdown' from GitHub:
  Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)`` and I can't find an installation file I can download manually.

Comment: Oh, basically in your case, you can't download anything from Github in R. Then you'll have to clone or download the repo https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown, and run `R CMD INSTALL` or `xfun::install_dir('path/to/blogdown')` to install it.

Comment: OK, that worked. Thanks very much for the help, @Yihui.  
Any idea why I can't install from Github?

Comment: I don't know. You may check if `libcurl` in `capabilities()` is TRUE. Or see if `xfun::download_file('https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/latest', tempfile())` works.

Comment: ``libcurl`` in ``capabilities()`` is TRUE. The ``xfun::download_file()`` doesn't work; same message about the problem with SSL CA cert.

Comment: Then I have no idea. I've never used Gentoo Linux before. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

A helpful user on the Gentoo forums provided the fix. I changed the USE flag from SSL_NSS to SSL_OPENSSL and that fixed it!